# Divide dataframe rows with one row frame in polars

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

I want to divide polars dataframe rows by a single row dataframe.
In pandas it can be done with df.divide.
Haven't found how to do it in polars.

I have achieved the result like this:

```
from itertools import repeat
import polars as pl
data = {'a': [i for i in range(1, 5)],
            'b': [i for i in range(1, 5)],
            'c': [i for i in range(1, 5)],
            'd': [i for i in range(1, 5)]}
    df = pl.DataFrame(data)
    divisors = pl.DataFrame({'d1': 1, 'd2': 10, 'd3': 100, 'd4': 1000})
    divisors_as_big_as_df = pl.concat([item for item in repeat(divisors, len(df))])
    divided_df = df / divisors_as_big_as_df
    print(df)
    print(divisors)
    print(divisors_as_big_as_df)
    print(divided_df)
```

And this is the output:

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   │
│ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
│ 4   ┆ 4   ┆ 4   ┆ 4   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
shape: (1, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┐
│ d1  ┆ d2  ┆ d3  ┆ d4   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 10  ┆ 100 ┆ 1000 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┘
shape: (4, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┐
│ d1  ┆ d2  ┆ d3  ┆ d4   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 10  ┆ 100 ┆ 1000 │
│ 1   ┆ 10  ┆ 100 ┆ 1000 │
│ 1   ┆ 10  ┆ 100 ┆ 1000 │
│ 1   ┆ 10  ┆ 100 ┆ 1000 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┘
shape: (4, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┬───────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c    ┆ d     │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64  ┆ f64   │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 0.1 ┆ 0.01 ┆ 0.001 │
│ 2.0 ┆ 0.2 ┆ 0.02 ┆ 0.002 │
│ 3.0 ┆ 0.3 ┆ 0.03 ┆ 0.003 │
│ 4.0 ┆ 0.4 ┆ 0.04 ┆ 0.004 │
└─────┴─────┴──────┴───────┘
```

But making that divisors_as_big_as_df is really time consuming.
So, is there a better way?

Comment: Is that `itertools.repeat` you're using?

Comment: Yes it is. 
import polars as pl
from itertools import repeat

Comment: Is there any difference if you `df / pl.concat([divisors] * df.height)` directly?

Comment: Small difference. With h=1396 w=30 dataframe: time with repeat 0.0263. Time with df / pl.concat([divisors] * df.height) 0.02199599996674806. Pandas divide 0.0006258999928832054
-----

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a massive df to perform elementwise division, you can just do the division column by column.

```py
df.with_columns(
    **{col: pl.col(col) / divisors[f"d{i+1}"] for (i, col) in enumerate(df.columns)}
)
```

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┬───────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c    ┆ d     │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64  ┆ f64   │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 0.1 ┆ 0.01 ┆ 0.001 │
│ 2.0 ┆ 0.2 ┆ 0.02 ┆ 0.002 │
│ 3.0 ┆ 0.3 ┆ 0.03 ┆ 0.003 │
│ 4.0 ┆ 0.4 ┆ 0.04 ┆ 0.004 │
└─────┴─────┴──────┴───────┘
```

Comment: I like it, another idea besides the enumerate is `zip(df.columns, divisors.columns)`

Comment: This results to 0.0013342000311240554 with With h=1396 w=30 dataframe. Good but still lacks from pandas divide.

Comment: What happens if you just set `divisors` to the dict instead of making it into its own DataFrame?

Comment: You could also try `df.with_columns(
    **{col: pl.col(col) / divisor for col, divisor in zip(df.columns, divisors.rows[0])}
)`